# SQL data to JSON files

Tags: php, sql

I have been able to export SQL data to JSON with a query. Now I want my files should not be bigger than 5MB for every table. If a table is bigger than 5MB, I want to split that file in `table_5m_1`, `table_5m_2` and so on.

The basics of exporting the data is complete and I have the following script doing it, but I am not sure what should I do to start splitting files so the JSON  data doesn't messing up

Doing this

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM items";  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

if( $stmt === false)
{
   echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";  
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

$json = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{    
     $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

In the above considering the use of offset and fetch so I can split the data like

```
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1000 
ROWS ONLY
```

the above will keep on appending the data to the same file and if that file reaches the limit of %mb, it will create a new file and start writing in there

I am ok to change the Process but really can't use the `bcp` command here and nothing related to `shell`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe there're a lot of tutorials over the web, which can show you where to start when working with files in `php`.

Comment: would love to, please share some code tutorials

Comment: Figure out how the items translate in size from memory to JSON-ified strings, work out a break point for detecting when you're going to go over that at your limit, and then start another array for passing to `json_encode()`. It's trickier than it sounds, but doable.